# Pastel Partner SDK Create Invoice Issue

Tags: c#, sdk

I am trying to generate an invoice in Pastel Partner using the SDK from a C# application. I have followed the documentation to a tee but I keep on getting a return code of 17 (Invalid customer account code). I have verified that the customer exists.

```
public string GenerateInvoiceDocument(Order order)
    {
        var result = _sdk.SetDataPath($"{_directory}{_company}");

        if (result == "0") _sdk.OpenDocumentFiles();
        var customer = GetCustomer(order.CustomerNumber);
        if (result == "0") {
            var header = "|||OIL004|05/03/2017||N|0|Message no.1|Message no.2|Message no.3|Delivery no.1|Delivery no.2|Delivery no.3|Delivery no.4|Delivery no.5||00||05/03/1999|011-7402156|Johnny|011-7402157|1";
            result =_sdk.DefineDocumentHeader(header);
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < order.InventoryCode.Count; x++)
        {
            if (result == "0")
            {
                var customerPrice = GetCustomerPrice(customer.Number, order.InventoryCode[x]);
                result = _sdk.DefineDocumentLine(
                    GenerateDocumentLine(
                           0,
                           Convert.ToDouble(order.Quantity[x]),
                           customerPrice.Price[x],
                           customerPrice.IncPrice[x],
                           "",
                           customer.TaxCode.ToString().PastelZeroPad(2),
                           "",
                           "",
                           customerPrice.ItemCode,
                           order.InventoryCode[x],
                           "4",
                           "002",
                           ""));
            }
        }
        result = _sdk.ImportDocument(3);
        _sdk.CloseDocumentFiles();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Warren, can you please advise how you managed to get hold of the actual SDK? We have a Pastel Partner subscription/setup but struggling to find the right path. Is it something you had to purchase?

Comment: Hi Bassie, yes it is an additional license that needs to be purchased. Pastel Partner support is pretty poor.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bit of buggy behaviour from Pastel, the solution was to remove any calcs from the Pastel flow by doing them beforehand.

```
public string GenerateInvoiceDocument(Order order)
    {
        var customer = GetCustomer(order.CustomerNumber);
        var header = GenerateCustomerDocumentHeader(customer, DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), order.Number, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), "", "", "", 1);
        var lines = new List<string>();
        for (var x = 0; x < order.InventoryCode.Count; x++)
        {
            var customerPrice = GetCustomerPrice(order.CustomerNumber, order.InventoryCode[x]);
            var newLine = GenerateDocumentLine(customerPrice.Price[x], (double)order.Quantity[x], customerPrice.Price[x], customerPrice.IncPrice[x], "0", customer.TaxCode.ToString(), "", "0", order.InventoryCode[x], order.InventoryDescription[x], "4", "001", "");
            lines.Add(newLine);
        }
        var result = _sdk.SetDataPath($"{_directory}{_company}");

        _sdk.OpenDocumentFiles();

        result = _sdk.DefineDocumentHeader(header, true);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            result = _sdk.DefineDocumentLine(line);
        }
        result = _sdk.ImportDocument(3, 0);

        _sdk.CloseDocumentFiles();

        return result;
    }
```